# How to set Enum in MYSQL database value with & symbol?

Tags: mysql

Does anybody know if it's possible and how I can set an enum value which includes the & symbol.

Such as:

Travel & Hospitality

I am currently getting the following:

```
&AMP;
```

Along with a MYSQL Error data trunicated.

Please can someone help me solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain more please?

Comment: @Tarekas mysql database does not like or will not let me use & symbol in an enum value. pure and simple. I don't know why. it just throws a hissy fit and shows a trunicated error message

Comment: 'will not let me use & symbol in an enum value' yes it does..https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/moLwPMRqeALgbXEguy9fmi/0 - what are you doing differently?

Comment: I suspect you're calling `htmlentities()` on your variable before storing it into the DB. That will convert `&` to `&amp;`